# mount -a - how to ignore partitions that are already mounted or partition that are busy

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

Some times when we do `mount -a` in order to mount all partitions we get the following error:

```
mount: /dev/sdc is already mounted or /grid/sdc busy
```

As I use `$?` to check in my Bash code the result of `mount -a`, in this case it will be nonzero.

Is it possible to do `mount -a` ignoring the partitions that are already mounted or partitions that are busy?

Comment: `mount -a` should never complain just because a partition is already mounted or because something is writing to a mounted partition. Is there something special about your mount point?

Comment: dr01 no I have 4 mount points and I get error from my log about already mounted         ., I use in my bash script only mount -a , and its very strange according to what you said , in this case from where I get already mounted